# Can't get Intellij to use the AspectJ compiler

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, aspectj, spring-roo

Everything I see online just says to select the "ajc" compiler from the list of compilers, but that's not an option for me. I've got javac, jikes, eclipse, and javac-in-process, but that's it.

As it is my project compiles from the command line with maven, but if I type anything in the IDE that uses an aspect, I get compiler warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure **AspectJ Support** plug-in is enabled in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Plugins`. [Follow the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/aspectj.html) for more details.

When using proper Maven project, **ajc** compiler will be enabled automatically.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. I was using the AspectJ Support plugin, but it wasn't working. I re-installed it and the option appeared.

Comment: Is the plugin available for intellij community edition ??

Comment: @Silent_Rebel no, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: alas "proper" doesn't work with nickwongdev branch of aspectj maven plugin for some reason

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t see this option you're maybe not using the ultimate edition.

> This option is available only in the Ultimate Edition of IntelliJ
>   IDEA.

[Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/java-compiler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late. here is my experience:
go to Settings --> Compiler --> Java Compiler

1. Set `Use Compiler` to `Ajc`
2. Set `Path to aspectjtools.jar` to something like the following: `~/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.1/aspectjtools-1.8.1.jar`